# Increase confidence score of handwritten text detected using google vision api

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I have to process a bunch of digital scanned documents which contain information as a form(mostly insurance, legal stuff). They are 90% printed text and 10% handwritten.
I used Google Vision API to extract information from them. It gave accurate results for printed texts with high confidence but handwritten parts were not always detected correctly.

So, is there any way to increase confidence of handwritten parts or can I customize API to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The API does its best to detect text from images (OCR). For better result, it is recommended to use image recommended size of 1024 x 768. Also, for handwritten texts, I suggest that you use [DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/handwriting) as the response is optimized for dense text and documents.

Comment: I have already used this API. I want to increase the confidence score of the response of this API to accurately extract handwritten text from forms.